# What's the 2D barcode on Google's new goo.gl URL shortner?

Tags: barcode

As per an example URL shortened here:

http://goo.gl/info/kW1c#week

What is the displayed 2D barcode for (copied here):

[image]

Comment: You're seeing dimensions where at least one of them doesn't exist (the image you show has height and width, it *doesn't* have depth). It's 2d, not 3d. Incidentally: you can see what it says at: [zxing.org](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx).

Comment: LOL, too long a day, yeah of course 2D barcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually a 2D barcode, and it is a QR code.  It is meant to print on stickers and what not to read with your cell phone camera.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code

Comment: Am I that far behind the times?  No doubt it represents the URL, BUT people are rushed that much to take pictures and then use an app to decode to go to a URL?

Comment: @Xepoch: Haven't done it myself, but sounds easier that typing it in. A half-dozen taps, maybe, versus a dozen just to type in a tinyurl.

Comment: I've started seeing them in ads and what not printed in newspapers and magazines.  I don't know if they are working for anyone, but if you've got the space and an audience that uses smart phones, it can't hurt.  We just used it on a poster for a campus radio station:  http://www.augustana.edu/users/bradisbell/WAUGPosterFall2010_small.jpg

Comment: Just some friendly constructive criticism - if your use of "what not" confused me (as an American) I can only imagine what it would do for non-American readers. It makes sense when somebody says it out loud, but it's confusing in written English (IMHO). ;-)

Comment: @senfo, thanks, I'll keep that in mind.  It's too bad English isn't more like a programming language, with logical structure that makes things clear.

Answer (score 1):

Takes you to the webpage of the shortened URL (usually for mobile devices that can read a QR code).

Comment: Dude, one day I'll have enough $ to get a cell phone contract, until then nothing like that on my pre-pay'd.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: printing these barcodes on a webpage is a common way to let people visit/bookmark that page from their phone (using the phone's camera and barcode reader function).

It is important to understand a barcode is a piece of text data, and not an instruction.  For example, the above bar code contains the text "http://goo.gl/info/kW1c".

It is the application reading the barcode which interprets it as an instruction. The data is read by a barcode reading application (for example, on a smart phone), and then an appropriate action is typically launched depending on the type of data. For example, if the text starts with "http://" a browser may be launched with that URL. If the data starts with "phone:" the phone application may be launch with that number.

Answer (score 1):

**bonus:**
to get a QR code for a goo.gl URL - append .qr :

http://goo.gl/kW1c.qr